# difference b\w clsParent.prototype and object.create(clsParent.prototype)

Tags: javascript, inheritance

how can i do prototypal inheritance in javasciript. usually i do by this
and

```
 derivedFn.prototype = object.create(clsParent.prototype)
```

but today i got we can also do this the result is same so what is the differce

```
derivedFn.prototype = clsParent.prototype
```

For example

```
function clsParent() {
    this.myName = "faizan"
    this.getMyName = function() {}
}
clsParent.prototype.aProp = "property in prototype"

function clsChild() {
    this.Fname = "abr"
}

clsChild.prototype = clsParent.prototype; //what is the difference
//Object.create(clsParent.prototype); 
// what is the difference if i do inheritance by this
var myObj = new clsChild();
console.log(myObj.myName);
console.log(myObj.aProp);
```

code is given please clarify me the difference of these two ways inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```
clsChild.prototype = clsParent.prototype;
```

You are making both the `clsChild` and `clsParent`'s prototypes the same. So, if you make changes to `clsChild.prototype`, the changes will be visible in any objects created with `new clsParent()` as well.

Try,

```
clsChild.prototype.a = 1000;
console.log(new clsParent().a);
// 1000
```

But when you do `Object.create(clsParent.prototype)`, it will create a brand new object which extends from `clsParent.prototype`. So, making changes to `clsChild.prototype` will not affect `clsParent.prototype`.

**Suggestion:**

It is usually a bad idea to store a property in the prototype, since it will be shared by all the instances. You should do this only if your usecase demands it.

```
clsParent.prototype.aProp = "property in prototype"; // Don't do this
```

Comment: and what about objec.create

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what `thefourtheye` said. I think it's mostly a matter of clarity. It's easier to think about objects when each class has an object to represent it. Additionally it's probably the most common way of implementing inheritance, which also makes it easier to understand.

Also there are no technical reasons not to store primitives values in a prototype. But it becomes confusing when you define integer properties in one part of the file, and array properties in another.